# Keeping `for /f` redirect the output / getting the `do ()` to happen during command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Okay, so I'm trying to automate an ARM based CPU stress test program (it runs through the command prompt, and requires quite a bit of user input). What I'd like to do, is use `for /f` to watch the output, and run a few different sendkeys scripts when it see's their respective prompt strings. I've tried making two very barebones batch files to test this out:

- The first is a simple batch file that asks for 3 separate inputs

  ```
  @echo off
  REM This is a file that asks for inputs
  set /p q1="Please press 1: "
  echo.
  set /p q2="Please press 2: "
  echo.
  set /p q3="Please press 3: "
  echo.
  echo All buttons have been pressed,
  echo.
  echo button 1 was: %q1%
  echo button 2 was: %q2%
  echo button 3 was: %q3%
  echo.
  set /p foo="Press Enter to finish..."
  ```
- The second is a batch file that runs the first (^) and looks for "Please Press 1: " in the output

  ```
  @echo off
  echo We will now launch the input command
  echo.
  timeout .5
  echo in 5...
  timeout 1
  echo 4...
  timeout 1
  echo 3...
  timeout 1
  echo 2...
  timeout 1
  echo 1...
  timeout 1
  echo Launching...
  for /f "delims= " %%i in ('Input.bat ^| find /i "Please press 1:"') do (
      echo we did it
  )
  echo Did you make the right decisions?
  set /p foo=
  ```

  What I get as a result of this is a blank command prompt right after the "Launching..." Echo. If I press Enter four times, it comes back with the "we did it" echo along with the "Did you make the right decisions?" echo. So, finally on to the meat of my question. Is there any way to keep `for /f` from redirecting the stdout, as well as, is there any way to get `for /f () do ()` to happen *while* the command is running?

Comment: Why not just combine both scripts into one batch file? The second file cannot read the variable of the closed batch 1 script as it no longer exists. Another option is to export the variables to a .txt file and have the 2nd batch then read them.

Comment: I don't quite understand how exporting the variable to a .txt would help (I'm definately on the Starting Out side of this) so if you could explain I'd really appreciate it. But to answer your first question, what I'm trying to do is automate a stress test that requires user input. As far as I can tell, its an executable that runs through the command prompt, I dont know if that works the same way as opening a batch file from a batch file, but I'd imagine it would do something very similar.

Comment: @Annabella Making a script now, i'll post it soon.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I think @Annabelle is thinking (or hoping) that the `for` command processes `Input.bat` line-by-line as they are executed. That is not the case though. The command inside the `()` of the `for` is ran to completion before the output is processed by `for`.

Comment: In response to @aphoria. Annabella are you tring to have the `FOR` statment wait for the input of Batch1..?

Comment: I'm trying to get the `for` statement to look, line by line, at the output of batch 2. Do you know if there's any way to get something to watch the output of another batch file in real time?

Comment: Perhaps your CPU stress test program accepts command line parameters or a config file? That would be your best option. Using SendKeys can be very problematic.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your request, sounds like you're trying to read strings from your `batch1` script from a new `batch2` script. To do this you will have to export your variables to a text document. From there, we can read the text document and gather the variables. If I am completely wrong on your request (It's a little hard to understand your request) then my oligopolies, hope those few tips can help you out at least.

To export files you need to use `>>`
For example: `Echo This will be line one! >> Yourfile.txt`

As another note, when you are done with the script, use `goto :eof` to exit.

**Here is your 1st batch file:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@DEL /Q %~dp0\strings.txt

REM This batch file asks for inputs
set /p q1="Please press 1: "
echo %q1% >> strings.txt
echo.
set /p q2="Please press 2: "
echo %q2% >> strings.txt
echo.
set /p q3="Please press 3: "
echo %q3% >> strings.txt
echo.
echo All buttons have been pressed,
echo.
echo button 1 was: %q1%
echo button 2 was: %q2%
echo button 3 was: %q3%
echo.

set /p foo="Press Enter to finish..."
goto :eof
```

**Here is your 2nd batch file:**

```
@ECHO OFF

echo We will now launch the input command.
echo.
echo in 5...
PING localhost -n 2 >nul
echo 4...
PING localhost -n 2 >nul
echo 3...
PING localhost -n 2 >nul
echo 2...
PING localhost -n 2 >nul
echo 1...
PING localhost -n 2 >nul
CLS
echo Launching...

:: Do action for each string. Use %%G to call the variable.
for /f "delims== tokens=*" %%G in (strings.txt) do (

echo Working on string: %%G

)

echo Did you make the right decisions?
pause > nul
DEL /Q %~dp0\strings.txt
goto :eof
```

Please keep in mind that instead of using `timeout 1` you can actually use `PING localhost -n 2 >nul` so it does not actually freeze the prompt it's self.

Comment: Interesting, I never actually thought about using a text file and reading from it like this. However, I understand now that my question is kindof confusing. So let me know if my clarification isn't helping. The goal of these two files is to find a method for reading the output of a command in real time, and reacting to it. Also, apparently commenting is restricted to a small number of characters, so I'll explain it in two.

Comment: I'm using a stress testing program for arm processors, and it needs to be run from the command prompt. That program requires me to answer a few sets of questions, and needs an input. The problem being, if you accidentally tap another key as you're trying to confirm the questions, it stops the test, and requires it to be re-done. This is not just infuriating, but takes a huge toll on productivity. So what I'm trying to achieve, is a program, or batch file that can recognize certain strings in the output, and run a sendkeys script to automatically respond to the prompts.

Comment: Due to limitations of batch, there are not many "Sendkeys" you can choose from (Example no letters or numbers). I suggest doing this in c# or finding a new program to stress test.

Comment: Do you have any advice on where to start trying to learn how to do this in c#?